# How to install the inter font on Arch with tex live

Tags: fonts

I want to install the inter fonr https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inter
in arch linux

is there a package for it or  do I have to copy it to a specific location? Where should it be copied?

```
ls /var/lib/texmf/arch/installedpkgs
texlive-core.fmts          texlive-langkorean.maps          texlive-langcyrillic_56674.pkgs
texlive-formatsextra.fmts  texlive-latexextra.maps          texlive-langextra_56781.pkgs
texlive-langjapanese.fmts  texlive-music.maps               texlive-langgreek_56956.pkgs
texlive-science.fmts       texlive-pictures.maps            texlive-langjapanese_57025.pkgs
texlive-core.maps          texlive-science.maps             texlive-langkorean_56915.pkgs
texlive-fontsextra.maps    texlive-bibtexextra_56991.pkgs   texlive-latexextra_57067.pkgs
texlive-games.maps         texlive-core_57066.pkgs          texlive-music_56473.pkgs
texlive-langchinese.maps   texlive-fontsextra_57042.pkgs    texlive-pictures_57065.pkgs
texlive-langcyrillic.maps  texlive-formatsextra_56699.pkgs  texlive-pstricks_56758.pkgs
texlive-langextra.maps     texlive-games_56833.pkgs         texlive-publishers_57058.pkgs
texlive-langgreek.maps     texlive-humanities_57034.pkgs    texlive-science_57068.pkgs
texlive-langjapanese.maps  texlive-langchinese_57044.pkgs


% pacman -Q | grep -i texlive
texlive-bibtexextra 2020.56991-1
texlive-bin 2020.54586-14
texlive-core 2020.57066-2
texlive-fontsextra 2020.57042-1
texlive-formatsextra 2020.56699-1
texlive-games 2020.56833-1
texlive-humanities 2020.57034-1
texlive-langchinese 2020.57044-1
texlive-langcyrillic 2020.56674-1
texlive-langextra 2020.56781-1
texlive-langgreek 2020.56956-1
texlive-langjapanese 2020.57025-1
texlive-langkorean 2020.56915-1
texlive-latexextra 2020.57067-1
texlive-music 2020.56473-1
texlive-pictures 2020.57065-1
texlive-pstricks 2020.56758-1
texlive-publishers 2020.57058-1
texlive-science 2020.57068-1
```

Comment: It is already in TeXLive so what exactly have you installed already?

Comment: I added the installed packages

Comment: The package seems very new so I I have it in my Upstream TeXLive installation. I don't think it is likely that any of the TeXLives from the Linux dists have it (which is why I never use LaTeX from a Linux dist, they are too far behind). There are some information in the `doc` folder on CTAN.

Comment: What do mean with `doc` folder  on CTAN ?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inter/doc

Comment: If you want to install it through `pacman`, you will have to go to https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-fontsextra/, flag it as out-of-date and add a comment pointing to the inter font, and hope that the package maintainer will get around to adding it.

Comment: Right now the version of texlive-fontsextra in Arch's beta-testing was packaged on April 10, which is a week before the inter font made it to CTAN. So it is possible that the package maintainer will want to wait a bit before pushing a newer version of the package.